# Error - One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event while installing Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

while installing sitecore eCommerce getting the error "One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event"

Error Log:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration :

        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }



            Server Error in '/' Application.
             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

            Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
it originated in the code.

            Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
            Source Error:

Line 52:         context.AddAspect<IFileInstallerEvents>(events);
Line 53:
Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context);
Line 55:
Line 56:         // Execute Post Step

             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\rglb.storefront\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx    Line:  54

            Stack Trace:

[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1848
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +135
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229
   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version) +343
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) +1304
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156
   Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context) +444
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\rglb.storefront\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\rglb.storefront\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4082


            Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0


At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
```

Comment: Which version? Please add more details about the setup itself.

Comment: Version: Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update-2

Comment: You should start by opening your `.showconfig.aspx` and looking at all handlers subscribed to the `item:saved` event. It should give you a start point on the troubleshoot at least.

Comment: Better to know on which package installation you got this error. Look at Error 3 in https://horizontalintegration.blog/2018/09/17/sitecore-9-ecommerce-installation-errors/ It should help.

Comment: my xConnect is working, still i was facing the same error. 
then i have commented the below event from "\App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceAnalytics\Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.config" file. 
<event name=”item:saved”>
</event>
this worked.

Answer (score 2):

Recently i got same issue and it comes when Sitecore is not able to connect with xConnect's Reference data service. This error comes when Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core package tries to install Experience Analytics Segments. As soon as it creates segment items, item:saved event deploys those items into xDB using xConnect Reference Data Service. If service is not available it generates error.

By disabling the processor you can continue XC installation but these segments needs to be deployed in xDB to collect commerce analytics data.

To deploy it after XC installation you can make sure your reference data service is working and configured properly in Sitecore connection strings. You can then deploy segments using Deploy marketing definitions tool from Sitecore Control Panel.